# algorithm and controlling comment lines (shifting right or left)

Tags: algorithms

I need to shift a comment to the right. Basically, in the below picture

[image]

The comment is distracting the pseudocode, therefore, I'm hoping to get the below picture

[image]

How to shift the comment to the right? This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,float}

%-----------
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\ALG@name~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{breakablealgorithm}
  \caption{PPPPPPPPPPPPP}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \makeatletter\setcounter{ALG@line}{0}\makeatother
  \If { $\phi < 10^\circ$}
        \State{$A = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa$} \Comment{ where \textbf{a} is aaaaaaaaaa   constant.}
        \Else
           \State{$B =  bbbbbbbbb$ }
        \EndIf  
\end{algorithmic}
\end{breakablealgorithm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox` (with `\raggedright` text if too narrow):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,float}

%-----------
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\ALG@name~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{breakablealgorithm}
  \caption{PPPPPPPPPPPPP}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \makeatletter\setcounter{ALG@line}{0}\makeatother
  \If { $\phi < 10^\circ$}
        \State{$A = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa$} \Comment{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright where \textbf{a} is some unknown constant.}}
        \Else
           \State{$B =  bbbbbbbbb$ }
        \EndIf  
\end{algorithmic}
\end{breakablealgorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]